# problem with Boolean field

Tags: lucene.net, nhibernate.search

I index a boolean field like this:

```
[Field(Index.UnTokenized, Store = Store.No)]
public virtual bool P { get; set; }
```

My query code looks like this:

```
public IList<MappedSequence> Query(string term, out int total, int page, int pageSize)
{
    if (term.ToString().Equals("") == false)
    {
    var parser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_29, new[] { "Query" }, new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_29));
    Query query = parser.Parse(term);

    IFullTextSession session = Search.CreateFullTextSession(this.Session);
    IQuery fullTextQuery = session.CreateFullTextQuery(query, new[] { typeof(MappedSequence) });
    total = fullTextQuery.List<MappedSequence>().Count();
    return fullTextQuery.List<MappedSequence>().Skip((page - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList<MappedSequence>();
    }
    else
    {
    total = 0;
    return null;
    }
}
```

This works fine for other index field but not for the boolean ones. I tried all sorts for term:

```
"P:\"TRUE\""
"P:\"1\""
```

without success. Any ideas what could be wrong?

BTW is there a more efficient way to determine total?

Thanks!

Christian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that if I use Tokenized for indexing it works.

Christian

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue,but in Lucene.Net 3.0 the syntax is "ANALYZED"

```
doc.Add(new Field("IsPrivate", objectName.IsPrivate.ToString(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
```

as opposed to "NOT_ANALYZED":

```
doc.Add(new Field("IsPrivate", objectName.IsPrivate.ToString(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
```